# Trouble passing arguments into os.system()

Tags: python, os.system

I want to run a python script 5 times. The output from each run is an image, and I want 5 images saved at the end. To do this I am using the os.system() command, and I end up with the following error:

```
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
i = 1

    while i < 6:
        run = os.system ('python main.py', 'input laska.png', 'output laska_save' + str(i) + '.png')
        i = i + 1
```

Not sure what the problem here might be. I essentially want the output argument to be `laska_save1, laske_save2 ... laska_save5`. The increment happens 5, once everytime after the called script runs.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: how are you taking inputs in main.py?  Did you know that you can take input directly as arguments without using `input` and `output` in os.system()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call it with just one string as follows:

```
os.system('python main.py input laska.png output laska_save{}.png'.format(i))
```

The `os.system` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) says it just take an string as argument, so you must create that full string with the command before passing it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

just format the string as the command you type in cmd prompt.
for example:
if `test.py` is a script which takes input file `file.csv` then the code will be

```
os.system("python {0} {1}".format(test_filepath,file.csv_filepath))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `main.py` is taking two arguments input file(`laska.png`) and the name of output file then your while loop will contain:-
`os.system('python main.py laska.png laska_save{}.png'.format(i))`